# How to get the link from content in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a post which a content with anchor tag I want to get the link

form the post content. Data stored in database following:-

```
<a href="https://www.manresa-sj.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/PhotoOfSteve.png">all data is here for you</a>


WP_Post Object
(

    [post_content] => all data is here for you

)
```

I want from the Post_content link like `https://www.manresa-sj.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/PhotoOfSteve.png`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want to extract the image link from the text.
use regex.

```
$string = '<a href="https://www.manresa-sj.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/PhotoOfSteve.png">all data is here for you</a>';

$pattern = '~(http.*\.)(jpe?g|png|[tg]iff?|svg)~i';

$m = preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```